# call from perl a large bash command

Tags: perl, bash, system

I want to call from perl the command "touch" on a large list of files.
The command I am using fails:

```
$cmd = "touch $list_of_files";
$ret=system("sudo -u user bash -c \"$cmd\"");
print $ret;
```

Is there a limitation of command length in bash or is it because I am using 'system'?
Beside splitting the list of files in smaller lists is there a solution to my problem?

Thanks

Comment: What is the error you get ? Did this solution work when you tried with a fewer number of files ?

Comment: Yes, with a smaller number it works. In the case it works ret=0, and ret != 0 if the command fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a limitation of command length in bash

I believe so. But why are you suing `bash` at all?

```
system("sudo", "-u", "user", "touch", @list_of_files);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It seems in my environement touch works only if i use bash -c.

Comment: Please never say "it doesn't work" again without specifying the important part: *How* it didn't work. Did you by "doesn't work" mean to say "No, that gives the error 'touch: command not found'"?

Comment: Did you notice the change from `$list_of_files` to `@list_of_files`? Don't do `$list_of_files = shell_quote(@list_of_files)` anymore. Pass the paths are separate args.

Comment: @georgiana_e, the problem might be that "user" does not have "touch" in the $PATH: use ikegami's advice (`system` with a list of arguments), but specify the full path to touch: `"/usr/bin/touch"` or whatever.